# Trying to execute a process with pkexec asynchronously and get 'Refusing to render service to dead parents'

Tags: root, process, vala, pkexec

I'm trying to execute a process as root from my application that runs with regular privileges using `pkexec`.

When I invoke `pkexec` synchronously everything is fine but when I run it asynchronously with the following code :

```
    private void execute_process_async () {

        if (permission.allowed ) {
            ...

            Pid child_pid;
            var cli = "%s/my_exec".printf (Build.PKGDATADIR);
            try {

                Process.spawn_async (null,
                    {   "pkexec", cli,
                        settings.scrollbar_width.to_string (),
                        settings.scrollbar_button_radius.to_string (),
                        settings.active_tab_underline_color
                    },
                    Environ.get (),
                    SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH,
                    null,
                    out child_pid);
            } catch (SpawnError e) {
                report_error ("error while executing '%s'. Message: '%s'.".printf (cli, e.message)) ;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get an a rather grim error message:

```
Refusing to render service to dead parents.
```

Do you know what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed to run `pkexec` in the background by fork and exec and then terminating the parent. The process becomes an orphan and belongs to `init` (ppid == 1). See https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2012-July/100103.html.

You're giving control of an application to another user (usually root). The default way is to run the application with `pkexec` as root from a shell script. This way the parent is a shell and not `init`.

E. g. GParted (`/usr/bin/gparted-pkexec`) and GameConqueror (`/usr/bin/gameconqueror`) do it like this as shown below:

1. Create a shell script as `/usr/local/bin/foo.sh`:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   pkexec "/usr/sbin/foo" "$@"
   ```
2. Give executable permission to above script:

   ```
   chmod +x /usr/local/bin/foo.sh
   ```
3. If you are using `.desktop` file, change `Exec` value as:

   ```
   Exec=/usr/local/bin/foo.sh
   ```
4. Make sure that your policy file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/` has following entry to allow GUI:

   ```xml
   <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
   ```

That’s it!

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this *[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433209/282415)* it worked for me.**

- It explains how to install policykit-1 which provides pkexec.
- explains usage for gui su prompt privilage escalation
- Bash alias setup for using aliases to run programs with out having to type

  ```
  pkexec application-name
  ```
- Instead it becomes alias(application-name):

  ```
  application-name
  ```